# How to show 404 error referer in apache logs

Tags: logs, apache-httpd

I need show the referrer for 404 error in the Apache log file.

I found only script in php, it's possible to make through Apache conf?

Answer (score 0):

You can have AccessLogs in [Combined Format](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/logs.html#combined), which will include Referer and status code:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog log/access_log combined
```

in your Apache configuration should do it.

Comment: Ok thanks, i have alredy this conf but some link not write in log, i now have confirmation that is correct.